# Role of push/pull and offset in Bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Bootstrap, and came across a few issues with `offset` and `push`/`pull` when used in the Bootstrap grid system.

The tutorial I'm following has this code:

```
 <!-- row 2 -->
    <div class="row">

        <article class="col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-sm-7 col-lg-push-3 col-sm-push-4">
            <h1>Services</h1>
            <p><img src="img/cockatiel.jpg" class="pull-right">Wisdom Pet Medicine is a state-of-the-art veterinary hospital, featuring the latest in diagnostic and surgical equipment, and a staff of seasoned veterinary specialists in the areas of general veterinary medicine and surgery, oncology, dermatology, orthopedics, radiology, ultrasound, and much more. We also have a 24-hour emergency clinic in the event your pet needs urgent medical care after regular business hours.</p>
            <p>At Wisdom, we strive to be your pet&rsquo;s medical experts from youth through the senior years. We build preventative health care plans for each and every one of our patients, based on breed, age, and sex, so that your pet receives the most appropriate care at crucial milestones in his or her life. Our overarching goal is to give your pet the best shot possible at a long and healthy life, by practicing simple preventative care. We even provide an online Pet Portal where you can view all your pet&rsquo;s diagnostic results, treatment plans, vaccination and diagnostic schedules, prescriptions, and any other health records.</p>
        </article>


        <aside class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-pull-9 col-sm-pull-8">
            <h3>Keeping your pet's chompers clean and healthy</h3>
            <p>You know the importance of brushing your own teeth, but did you know that dogs and cats also need regular attention to their pearly whites? Poor dental hygiene in pets can lead to periodontal disease, a bacterial infection which causes bad breath, drooling, tooth decay, and tooth loss.</p>
            <p>As always, if you have questions about your pet’s dental or health care, please <a href="#">contact Wisdom Pet Medicine</a> for advice.</p>
        </aside>
    </div>
```

The order in which this code was written follows this approach - First the large/small classes were added, then the offset was added, and last the push/pull class was added. I'm having some trouble in figuring out how these three work together.

Just picking out the `col-lg-*` scenario, for example, how does the `push/pull` work with the existing `col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-1` for `article` and `col-lg-3` for `aside`?

The way I had it was:

1. First the `col-lg-*` measurements were added both for the article and aside columns. So, the article occupied 8 columns and the aside occupied 3 columns.
2. Then `col-lg-offset-1` was added to article, so it would be pushed 1 col towards the right, in other words - towards the aside, even though it should have been the other way around. But I guess this is because in the next step, articles and aside would be swapped through `push/pull`, which would then make sense.
3. `col-lg-push-3` was added to article, and `col-lg-pull-9` was  added to aside. This is where i'm stuck. Essentially you want the article to occupy 9 columns, so why is `col-push-3` added to it? Common logic says it should be `push-9`. Same goes for aside.
4. Last, once the article and aside are swapped with `push/pull`, how is the offset applied? With the `push/pull` being applied, article covers 9 columns and aside covers 3 columns. So where did the 1 column of offset go, that was originally applied to article? Are those `col-lg-*` measurements now overridden?

Many thanks for all the help!

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792778/what-is-the-difference-between-push-and-offset-under-the-grid-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my understanding about Bootstrap 3 grid system:

- All column dimensions are calculated using the `border-box` model. So, when we change the value of `border-width` and `padding` properties, the **real width** column is not changed.
- The width of the column is set by the `.col-xx-n` class.It is set to n/12 of the width of the parent container (the `.row` element)
- The position of the column is set via two methods:

  - The `.col-xx-offset-n` class moves the column to the **right** by a value of n/12 of the width of the container. This is done by applying a value of `n * 100% / 12` to the `left-margin` property to the column.
  - The `.col-xx-push/pull-n` class moves the column to the **left**/**right** by a value of n/12 of the width of the container. This is done by applying a value of `n * 100% / 12` to the `left`/`right` property to the column.

For example, let see your `article` element in large screen. We divide the current `.row` element to 12 columns, called column 1 - column 12.

- Its width is set to 8/12 of the width of the `.row` element. Its position now is from 1st column to 8th column.
- It is pushed towards the right 1 column by the `.col-lg-offset-1` class. Now, Its position now is from 2nd column to 9th column (its left margin fills the 1st column).
- When the `.col-lg-push-3` class is applied to the column, the column itself is now moved to the left 3 columns. Its position now is from 4th column to 11th column.
- Remember the `.col-lg-offset-1` class and it left margin? The left margin fills the 4th column now. Finally, the column position now is from the 5th column to the 12th column.

Hope this help.