# what's exactly the purpose of col-md-offset-*?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What's exactly the purpose of `col-md-offset-*`?

I know the purpose of `col-md-12` without the offset. but with that I've no idea, I've tried to play with it but still nothing.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: Do you have some code that's not working? Offset works as you'd expect.. it "offsets" the column X number of units. http://codeply.com/go/qp27dZ7VGA

Comment: Read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792778/what-is-the-difference-between-push-and-offset-under-the-grid-system

Comment: It adds the margin to the left side, so other column will move to right side

Answer (score 3):

Short version of answer. Offset make empty column with custom width before our  column with data. If you want to make empty column with custom width after your column with data then use pull (col-md-pull-*).

**Example:**
In medium size window we want to create 2 empty cells, 7 cells with content and again 3 empty cells. We could do that this way.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-7 col-md-pull-3">OUR CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

And this is how it would look like without offsets. We should create empty divs with custom width.

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7">OUR CONTENT</div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Move columns to the right using .col-md-offset-* classes. These classes increase the left margin of a column by * columns. For example, .col-md-offset-2 moves .col-md-2 over four columns.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2">First col-md-2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2"> col-md-2 with offset 2</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> .col-md-offset-* to leave a particular number of virtual Bootstrap columns to the left of any column (kind of like invisible place holders).
>
> It is used for giving space from margin-left, you can see in my example first div is used with offset thats why it is displaying from margin left

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4  col-md-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

So `col-md-12` will take up the whole of the preceding div. But what happens if you dont want to take up the whole div?
Say you only want to take up half the div but want to centre the content then you can do `col-md-6 col-md-offset-3` This will make a div of 6 cols wide and offset it by 3. So the content starts 3 cols in and then goes for 6 cols.
You should really read the bootstrap docs about their grid system and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to move columns to the right. For details, access http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: Provide context for links

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

col-md-offset-* give margin from left. Like if i need col-md-6 on right but not on left then we need to add "col-md-offset-6" with col-md-6.

Example:
`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6"></div>
</div>`

Try to add this html in your editor and check output in browser.

Answer (score 0):

> It is used for giving space from margin-left, you can see in my example first div is used with offset thats why it is displaying from margin left

Try to resize your browser or on other devices to see: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Here is my screenshot on large screen (`col-lg-*` applied), view it on `Inspect`
[image: my screenshot on large screen]

`.col-md-offset-2` make a space between 2 `col-md-*` in a `row`, check image below.

Here is my screenshot on medium screen (`col-md-*` applied), view it on `Inspect`

[image: my screenshot on medium screen]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2">First col-md-2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2"> col-md-2 with offset 2</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4  col-md-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

According to W3School: it is similar to margin-left, but with unit as col. You can [try it yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex8&stacked=h) or [read reference](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp) there.