# How to float div elements when using col-*-pull or col-*-push?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, pug, grid-layout

I have a sample page with three `div`s as bellow:

```html
<body class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-push-0"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-lg-pull-0"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-push-0"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

When browser size reach to `md` point and 2nd `div` is higher than first `div` the 3rd `div` goes to right side of first one. how I should change the grid implementation to fix it? 
I have the code on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Alidadi/pen/ygBRoR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sytax error:

No need of `col-lg-4.col-md-6` replace it to `col-lg-4 col-md-6`

```
 <body class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-push-0"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-lg-pull-0"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-push-0"></div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

And also if you replace the last col-md-push-6 and col-lg-push-0 to col-md-offset-6 and col-lg-offset-0. It should behave the way you wanted.

Here is forked [codepen](http://codepen.io/rachitgulati26/pen/vgYOom/)

This happened because offset works in different way than push in bootstrap. [Here is reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792778/what-is-the-difference-between-push-and-offset-under-the-grid-system)

Comment: Thanks for your attention

Comment: @SaeidAlidadi I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: You did not changed I see :)

Comment: Hey @SaeidAlidadi I have updated the codepen please check. It helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<body class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 col-lg-push-0"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-lg-pull-0"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 col-lg-push-0"></div>
   </div>
 </body>
```